# In Visual Studio, is it possible to export a .xlsx of a c# script "skeleton"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

If possible, I would like to be able to take a c# script and export a "listing" of all the classes, properties, methods etc. to an excel document.  I don't need to export the code within each method.  I just want a breakdown of a particular script in excel form.  I feel like this should probably be possible within Visual Studio but my searches haven't turned up anything.  Basically a meta data export for any given script.

For an example, if I have the following code as a .cs file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assets.Scripts_SinglePlayer_TB.Scripts.Working_Junk
{
    class TestClass
    {
        int property1;
        string property2;
        float property3;

        void changeIntProperty(int num)
        {
            property1 = num;
        }

        void changeStringProperty(string str)
        {
            property2 = str;
        }

        void changeFloatProperty(float flt)
        {
            property3 = flt;
        }

        void printStuff()
        {
            Debug.Log("Prop1: " + property1.ToString());
            Debug.Log("Prop2: " + property2.ToString());
            Debug.Log("Prop3: " + property3.ToString());
        }

    }

    class junkClass
    {
        int test1;
        int test2;

    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow output something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "C# script"? A program? A project? A class? A CSX file? Something else?

Comment: For example, a single .cs document from within a c# project.  I just want to export a listing of all the class definitions, and property/method definitions within each class.

Comment: Namespaces also, the particular document I'm looking at doesn't contain and namespace definitions, but it is possible in others.

Comment: If you want to read _files_, you will need to use [Visual Studio Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx). It would be much easier to use Reflection to load an assembly, list all the classes in it, and then extract the information from them.

Comment: @ stuartd I guess I'm just not that savvy...  I looked at your link for VSE and I'm not saying it doesn't, but I don't understand how that helps.  I really just want a "collapsed" document that shows all of the classes, properties, and methods within a given document.  I'm going to rework my original question with an example of what I'm going for.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: have a look at [How to get Classes and methods from a .cs file using Reflections in C#.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906483/how-to-get-classes-and-methods-from-a-cs-file-using-reflections-in-c)